# Proper use of app.set in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently following https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens. However, I do not understand the need for ...

```
app.set('superSecret', config.secret);
```

... when you could just continue using `config.secret`. Can someone kindly explain this to me? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply allows you to access your values via `app.settings.superSecret` and nothing else.

The good thing about this is, you won't have to keep importing your `config` object to every file! You can simply grab the value straight from ***app.settings***.

It really comes down to personal choice.

I recommend you read up on the docs over at express: expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

The reason for a global config file is so you can use specific environments and ***hide*** the secret data from say github or bitbucket (some sort of version control service). You wouldn't be uploading your secret details to github, bitbucket, or any other similar service. When I say environments I mean production, development, local, and etc. You could have a function inside your config file that returns a specific objects. E.g

```
var env = {
  production: {
  ... env vars
  },
  local: {
  ... local vars
  }
}

export default env["production"]; // You would change something here or
```

Note this is a very basic example of what you could do to change your environment variables. You can simply change `env["production"] to env["local"]` to swap your environment.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, if you look at the example... you will note that the author has created a `config.js` file especially for hosting global configuration files... I am wondering why he didn't just use `app.set` for all the variables instead. Why would anyone create a global config file and then still use `app.set` as well? Is this recommended?

Comment: Latest Express documentation is at https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Comment: @James111 Thank you so much for the explanation buddy.

Comment: No worries @Grateful When I first got into node I was interested in this sort of stuff.

Comment: I know this is kind of old now. But still... can it's will be better to set the superSecret value in a .env file and get it as an environment variable, is not ?

It's what I force myself to do for value like database connexion string on mLab or stuff from heroku...

Answer (score 0):

use [**express session**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

**server.js**

```
var config = require('./config');
var session = require('express-session');
 app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret
 }));
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
 sessionSecret: "very-secret" // or if loading from your .env **sessionSecret:process.env.SECRET**
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question exactly?